# Changing from lists to arguments in Python 3.0

Tags: python, counter

I've recently constructed a piece of python code which finds the least commonly repeated number in a list! Here is my code...

from collections import Counter

```
def least_common():

from collections import Counter

List = [1,1,1,0,0,3,3,2]

CountList = Counter(List)

Mincount = min(CountList.values())

least_common = next(n for n in reversed(List) if CountList[n] == Mincount)

print (least_common)
```

least_common()

However as you can clearly see, this uses a list to call the numbers which will be compared. 
I'm now trying to get it to do the same task, but instead of using a built in list, I want it to use an argument of integers.

For example

```
def the_least_common(integers)

--------code with argument which will find lowest repeated number---------

   print the_least_common([1,1,1,0,0,3,3,2])
```

LEAST COMMON BEING 2

Is any of the code which I've already created reusable for what I now need to create? Apologies if this is a stupid question or comes across as really simple as I'm a little stuck

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Sorry @Shadow Code now formatted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `Counter`, there's a builtin method - [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) - that returns a sorted list of elements and their counts, starting with the most common first. You can query the last element of this list.

```
In [418]: Counter([1,1,1,0,0,3,3,2]).most_common()[-1]
Out[418]: (2, 1)
```

Your function would look something like this:

```
def least_common(data):
    return Counter(data).most_common()[-1][0]
```

---

If your data can have multiple integers with the same least count, and your function needs to return every one of them, you can iterate over `most_common`:

```
def least_common(data):
    c = Counter(data).most_common()[::-1]
    yield c[0][0]

    for x, y in c[1:]:
        if x != c[0][1]:
            break
        yield y
```

Comment: I know the OP didn't specify this, but strictly speaking, there could be more than one least common element.

Comment: @Os9008 So what's the problem here?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Sorry I  didn't manage to finish my comment. My def needs to be def the_least_common(integers) and call print the_least_common([1,1,1,0,0,3,3,2]) for the specification of the program unfortunately. Thanks for the tip anyway

Comment: @Os9008 in what way is my answer different from your "specification" besides the missing "the" in the function name?

Comment: Never mind mate, I've cracked it! I feel dandy now! I'm new to programming and I'm pretty happy that I found a solution! Thanks for the help anyway :) @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: @Os9008 If my answer helped, you could mark it accepted, or post your own answer and accept that. Up to you.